# Update user profile in website

Tags: asp.net, sql-update

In my website made by asp.net, we can update the email address, password, place and about myself of a user given the old password is correct. Now what I do is, login, then use this code to update:

```
 protected void update_profile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Khulna_website"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string user_email = (string)(Session["User"]);
            string pass = encrypt_pass(old_password.Text);
            if (pass != (string)(Session["Password"]))
            {
                pass_err_message.Text = "Wrong password";
                pass = (string)Session["Password"];
            }
            else
            {
                pass = encrypt_pass(new_password.Text);
            }
            string insertQuery = "update dbo.users set user_password=@new_password, user_place = @new_place, user_about=@new_about where user_email =" +user_email;
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
            connection.Open();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_password", pass);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_about", new_about.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_place", new_place.Text);
            try
            {
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                upload_err_message.Text = "Successfully uploaded";
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                profile_settings_err_message.Text = "Update error: " + ex.Message;
            }

        }

    }
```

But when I try to update it is saying: Update error: The multi-part identifier "abcde@gmail.com" could not be bound. And my session is gone! I thought maybe it was due to foreign key, so I removed all the foreign keys of the database, but it is still happening. What's wrong here?

EDIT: I have added back the foreign keys, since I need them to on delete cascade. I just deleted them to see if it works.

Comment: You shouldn't form SQL queries by string concatenation. If you ever see that, it's a giant code smell. You should stop and re-evaluate: you likely need to be using parameters. If you don't follow this advice, you can get escaping issues like you got, or even worse, [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You appear to be storing passwords in encrypted form. This is not a good idea. Passwords should be one-way hashed and salted. Then you would compare hashed forms of the passwords to determine validity.

Comment: Thanks, I will look after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just taking a guess, but I believe your issue will be found right here:

```
"... user_email =" +user_email;
```

Try doing something like

```
"... user_email = @email";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user_email);
```

That's the better way... however if you want to get lackadaisical you should be able to just surround the email in single quotes.

```
"... user_email = '" + user_email + "'";
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it works, but the session goes off! But why it wasn't working before?!

Comment: Maybe the session is timing out? I don't know how your application is set up, but it is possible. 

Not sure why the session wasn't working, I just know you should always sanitize your queries!